# What are the functions satisfying $f\left(2\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{3^i}\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{2^i}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, functions

> I am interesting of finding for all monotone functions $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ satisfying 
>    the relation 
>   $$f\left(2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{3^i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{2^i}$$
>   Where $a_i\in \{0,1\}$

I have tired to see whether I could make some conjecture. Namely, such function must satisfy the point-wise relations

$$f(0)=0~~~~~a_i=0~~~~\mbox{for $i\ge 1$}~~~and~~~f(1)=1~~~~~a_i=1~~~~\mbox{for $i\ge 1$}$$

$$f(\frac23)=\frac12~~~~~a_1=1,a_i=0~~~~\mbox{for $i\ge 2$}$$

$$f(\frac13)=\frac12~~~~~a_1=0,a_i=1~~~~\mbox{for $i\ge 2$}$$

continuing this way we can find particular values. But I cannot find a conjecture on this

Can any one help?

Comment: Your condition determines the values at the Cantor set, and since the image of that set will be all of $[0,1]$, there is going to be exactly one such function, namely [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

Comment: To elaborate on WojoWu's comment one can check that f has the same value at the end points of each of the intervals removed in the construction of Cantor set. This forces f to be a constant on the intervals removed, by monotonicity. Hence f must be the Cantor function.